# How to add ADDON in stripe susbcription?

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

Is there a way to add multiple plans with different type in the same subscription?

I am trying to add two plans (one is recurring type and the other one single type) but stripe subscription not accepting it. Getting this error

Comment: What type of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. While the `items` property only accepts recurring prices, you can use the `add_invoice_items` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-add_invoice_items) to add one time prices to the first invoice, when creating your subscription. Like this:

```js
// Example in Node.js
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: `{CUSTOMER_ID}`,
  items: [
    {
      price: ‘{RECURRING_PRICE_ID}’,
    },
  ],
  …
  add_invoice_items: [{
    price: `{ONE_TIME_PRICE_ID}`,
  }]
})
```